# SQL Select Many to Many

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

I'm using MYSQL 5.X and I'm having trouble figuring out a Query;

I have 2 entities with a many to many relationship.

client and service, therefore I have 3 tables:

clients, clients_has_services and services.

I need to Select EVERY Service that is NOT related to a particular client.

for example:
I have client with ID 1, and 4 Services in Total (Service1, Service2, Service3, Service4), client 1 has a relationship with Service1) so I need to retrieve all Other services (Service2, Service3, Service4)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get a set all `services`.

Join that to the row from `clients` for the "particular client", so you have a set of all services for the client.

The "trick" is to use an anti-join pattern to exclude rows where you have "matches" in the `clients_have_services` table.

If you have the unique identifier for the client (and you only need the list for a single client), something like this:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM services s
  LEFT
  JOIN clients_have_services h
    ON h.service_id = s.id
   AND h.client_id = 42
 WHERE h.service_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY s.id
```

The outer join returns all rows from `services`, along with any "matching" rows from the `clients_have_services` table.  The "trick" is the predicate in the WHERE clause that *excludes* any rows where a match was found, leaving just the `services` that are not related to the particular client.

If you are doing this for multiple clients... you'd need to also return the client cross joined with services (as cross product of clients and services), and then exclude the matches.

For example:

```
SELECT c.id AS client_id
     , s.*
  FROM clients c
 CROSS 
  JOIN services s
  LEFT
  JOIN clients_have_services h
    ON h.service_id = s.id
   AND h.client_id = c.id
 WHERE h.service_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY c.id, s.id
```

---

There are a couple of other query patterns that will return an equivalent result, for example, a `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM services s
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM clients_have_services h
          WHERE c.client_id = 42
            AND h.service_id = s.id
       )
 ORDER BY s.id
```

Comment: you answer worked,, but you typed an 'n' instead of the 'h' after the AND

Comment: That was a typo. (To my eyes, An n looks a lot like an h. (At least the query would have returned an error, not wrong results.)

Comment: ya, ty for the explanation :D thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your client_has_services rectifies the many-to-many so you have one to many on both sides, so your client_has_services should have:
ID (Key), Client_ID, Service_ID

`SELECT * FROM services WHERE services.id != ANY (select client_has_services.services_id from client_has_services where client_has_services.client_id = ID_num_provided)`

Comment: Won't this query throw an error when the subquery returns more than one row? Maybe if the `!=` inequality comparison was replaced with a `NOT IN` operator, and we guaranteed that the subquery doesn't return a NULL value, this would work.

Comment: If it returns more than one row, its not a problem. It will re-run the "superquery" for each row returned. Seems counter intuitive, but it works.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that behavior, or an example that demonstrates it? I'd expect the query in your answer to raise Error 1242 "Subquery returns more than 1 row".  [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-errors.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-errors.html)

Comment: Updated to include "ANY" after the comparator. Should work in accordance with your link now.
I've done this a lot in Oracle, the syntax there doesn't require the ANY operator and works well with multiple rows returned. My mistake for missing that at first.